# escaping an apostrophy in a jxa doshellscript

Tags: javascript, javascript-automation

in a **jxa script** i am running a shell script that runs osascript with mulitple -e arguments containing a multiline applescript which normally work just fine.  this one will not work however.  the apostrophy in the word `range's` is not being interpreted propertly with the doShellScript command.  the same command on the cli works just fine.

in particular `-e 'set theData to used range's value'` argument.

i tried `range\'s, range\\'s, range\\\'s, range\\\\'s, range&apos;s` and many other ideas from this site but to no avail so far.  following is the full line of code in question.  ideas are welcome, thank you.

`input = app.doShellScript("/usr/bin/osascript -e 'set startRow to 1' -e 'set StartCol to 3' -e 'set myCol to 1' -e 'set myRow to 1' -e 'set pollListImportIsYes to {}' -e 'set pollList to {}' -e 'tell application \"Microsoft Excel\"' -e 'tell active sheet' -e 'set theData to used range's value' -e 'repeat with colNum from StartCol to 102' -e 'set cellVal to item {colNum} of item {startRow} of theData' -e 'if cellVal = "y" then' -e 'repeat with rowNum from 1 to 14' -e 'set cellVal to item {colNum} of item {rowNum} of theData' -e 'copy cellVal to the end of pollList' -e 'end repeat' -e 'copy colNum to the end of pollListImportIsYes' -e 'copy cellVal to item (myCol) of item {myRow}' -e 'end if' -e 'end repeat' -e 'end tell' -e 'end tell' -e 'return pollList'");`

Comment: Why on earth are you running applescript inside osascript inside a jxa script ?  Why not pick one, and just do it all in that ?  This is totally absurd.

Answer (score 1):

This is the JXA implementation of your `osascript`'s AppleScript.  It negates the need to worry about apostrophes, and reduces the layers of subprocesses that were being instantiated for each invocation of the three different scripting environments.

```js
const Excel = Application('Microsoft Excel');
const Sheet = Excel.activeSheet();
const data  = Sheet.usedRange.value();

const startRow = 0,
      startCol = 2,
      myCol    = 0, 
      myRow    = 0;
 
var pollListImportIsYes = [], 
    pollList            = [];

for(let colNum = startCol; colNum < 102; colNum++){ 
    let cellVal = data[startRow][colNum];
    if (cellVal==='y') {
        for(let rowNum = 0; rowNum < 14; rowNum++){
            cellVal = data[rowNum][colNum];
            pollList.push(cellVal);
        } // for: rowNum 
        pollListImportIsYes.push(colNum); 
        Sheet.rows[myRow].columns[myCol].value = cellVal; 
    } // if 
} // for: colNum 


const input = pollList;
console.log(input);
```